# Unable to get fgets() and strcat() to behave in desired way

Tags: c, string, fgets, strcat

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"

int main(){
    char storage[128]="\0";
    char buffer[24];
    fgets(buffer, 24, stdin);
    strcat(storage, buffer);
    fgets(buffer, 24, stdin);
    strcat(storage, buffer);
    printf("%s", storage); // line 12
    return 0;
    }
```

I am trying to see that `line 12` prints `"string one\0string two"` when I enter `"string one"` and `"string two"` on previous `fgets()` lines but instead, it prints `"string one\nstring two"`. As far as I know `strcat()` terminates the `"\0"` at the end of the first string so this code should have given me the format I wanted, but it does not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `char storage[128]="\0";` --> `char storage[128]="";` the string terminator will be added by the compiler.

Comment: @WeatherVane I have updated my code in the way you suggested and I am still having the same behavior.

Comment: Do you mean it still prints `"string one\0string two"` after making the change I suggested? Note that `fgets()` retains the `newline` at the end, is that what you are seeing?

Comment: @WeatherVane What I want is `"string one\0string two"`, but it gives me `"string one\nstring two"`. So, after I made the change you suggested, it still gave me `"string one\nstring two"`. At least that's what I'm seeing on the screen, basically string one printed on one line and string two is on the next line as if there were a `"\n"` inbetween.

Comment: You can remove the trailing newline retained by `fgets()` like this: it is safe even when there is no newline present. `buffer [ strcspn(buffer, "\r\n") ] = 0;` However you will get `"string onestring two"` and not `"string one\0string two"`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you for the tip. I was planning to use `buffer[strlen(buffer)-1]=0;` but not sure which one would work better. I'll try it both ways. Add: Just found out `strlen()` doesn't work good when the input string fills the buffer completely. So I guess I'm going with `strcspn()`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The result `"string one\nstring two"` is correct because the newline is read by fgets. You input the newline when you press enter to end the input.

> A newline character makes fgets stop reading, but it is considered a valid character by the function and included in the string copied to str.